# What SQL Statements does dolphindb support?

Tags: sql, syntax, dolphindb

In the manual of dolphindb, it supports select, insert and update statements:

```
select [top_clause] column_expressions
from table_name | table_expression
[where filter_conditions]
[grouping_clause [having_clause] | order_clause]
```

In fact, I find it also supports delete:

```
delete from table_name where condition(s);
```

Well, what other SQL statements does Dolphindb support?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you just listed the elements of the `select` statement here.

The documentation lists the [SQL statements DolphinDB supports](http://www.dolphindb.com/help/Chapter8SQLStatements.html), and `delete` is explicitly stated there.